# How to copy website with fetch method in Angular? I need code , maybe video or instruction

Tags: angular, methods, fetch

I have to copy the site , with fetch method and need help

I am learning and can not find materials, preferable will be videos or simply typescript,css and html codes to analyze and understand. If someone has good material and can share thanks in advance